# Setting bounds for image overlay in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, overlay, maps

I'm using LeafletJS map. I need to use an image overlay. I have done it like so:

```
onMapReady(event: any) {
   this.layers.push(imageOverlay(this.imgSrc + "map.png", [[35.334847, 25.328072], [35.337847, 25.339072]])); // This is the overlay
}
```

I can see the small image overlay as below. But how can I show it the whole screen? I think the problem here is set bounds. But how can I set it? I have center  `"lat": "35.335847",`
        `"lon": "25.338072",` If this is the center (i.e. with arrow) then how can I show the image entire page? Any clue about how to set the bounds and find out those `lat` and `lon` for that?

[image: Example]

Comment: Am I correctly understand that your marker is the centre with the following coordinates `"lat": "35.335847", "lon": "25.338072"`?

Comment: Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103561/leafletjs-image-overlay-set-bounds

Comment: @Taras Yes, you're right. Then how can I set the bounds? I need to show that image entire page.